# Delete using subquery and intersect?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-delete, intersect

I am trying to delete using the below query but unfortunately, all the records are deleted

```
DELETE [dbo].[devicelinks]
FROM   
    (SELECT *
     FROM [dbo].[devicelinks]
     WHERE PID = 7

     INTERSECT 

     SELECT * 
     FROM ASC.dbo.DEVICE_LINK
     WHERE PID = 7)
```

How to properly use the subquery to delete the  corresponding records from the source table?

No keys or constraints in either of the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
delete [dbo].[devicelinks]
from [dbo].[devicelinks]
    inner join ASC.dbo.DEVICE_LINK
     on [dbo].[devicelinks].PID = ASC.dbo.DEVICE_LINK.PID
where [dbo].[devicelinks].PID = 7
```

Comment: i can try this but i need to check more than one column in my binding list

Comment: You can add on the the join clause like this  " and [dbo].[devicelinks].MyField= ASC.dbo.DEVICE_LINK.MyField" You cha have as many of these as required

Comment: Which is recommended ,  subquery  or join

Comment: I checked and @Martin Smith is right the query optimizer creates the same plan for both, so it ends up being up a matter of style, i prefer the join as it reads easier for me.

Comment: Usually, i prefer subquery as I find it hard to master and the diversity it provides.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` to detect the records to be deleted:

```
DELETE d1
FROM [dbo].[devicelinks] d1
WHERE PID = 7 AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM ASC.dbo.DEVICE_LINK AS d2
                          WHERE d1.PID = d2.PID AND
                                d1.[DEVICEID] = d2.[DEVICEID] AND
                                ... rest of the fields here )
```

Comment: you may get performance issues with a EXISTS and nested join on larger datasets.

Comment: @RegBes - You may get performance issues with any query against larger datasets. `EXISTS` is not inherently worse than your answer which I assume you are trying to imply. SQL Server has a semi join logical operator that can do this at least as efficiently as a regular join.